# Probability of individual committee to be correct is larger than one individual

Tags: probability

There is a committee with $n\ge3$ (and $n$ is odd) members. The probability of any one of the members to give a correct answer(yes/no) for a question is $P>0.5$ and there is no dependency between the members. The committee answer to the question is decide by the majority rule.

How can I show that the probability of the committee to answer correct is larger than $P$ (the probability of one of the members to answer correct)?

I succeed to show that it is correct for $n=3$ but Im not sure how to generalize it for any $n\ge3$ (maybe induction?)

tnx

Comment: how is defined the probability of the committee?

Comment: the probability that more than half of the members vote correctly

Answer (score 1):

Define:

$$P_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{k}p^{2n+1-k}(1-p)^{k}$$

This is the probability that a committee of size $2n+1$ gets the answer correct.

The probability they get the wrong answer is:

$$Q_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{2n+1-k}$$

So $P_n+Q_n=1$, but a simple term-by-term comparison shows that if $k\in\{0,1,\dots,n\}$ and $p>\frac{1}{2}$ then $p^k(1-p)^{2n+1-k}<p^{2n+1-k}(1-p)^k$, which is true since $(1-p)^{2n+1-2k}<p^{2n+1-2k}$. Thus $Q_n<P_n$ and hence $P_n>\frac{1}{2}$.

---

Alternatively can see deduce the inductive rule:

$$\begin{align}P_{n+1}&=\left(P_n-\binom{2n+1}{n}p^{n+1}(1-p)^n\right) + (2p-p^2)\binom{2n+1}{n}p^{n+1}(1-p)^n+p^2\binom{2n+1}{n+1}p^n(1-p)^{n+1}\\
&=P_n+p^{n+1}p^n\binom{2n+1}{n}\left(-1+2p-p^2+p(1-p\right)\\
&=P_n+p^{n+1}p^n\binom{2n+1}{n}(2p-1)(1-p)
\end{align}$$

[This can be expressed as: "The probability that you get $n+2$ correct answers in your first $2n+1$ answers, plus the probability that you get $n+1$ in the first $2n+1$ answers and at least one correct answer of the last two, plus the probability that you get $n$ correct answers in the first $2n+1$ and then two correct answers.]

So when $\frac{1}{2}<p<1$, $P_{n+1}>P_n$. (For $p=1$ you get $P_n=1$ for all $n$.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, let us model a voting of our committee with a string of length $n$ with elements $0$ or $1$, where $1$ corresponds to positive vote and $0$ to negative vote.

So, the possible outcomes where the committee votes positive are all strings with more than $\frac{n}{2}+1$ $1$'s, or:
$$\sum_{k>\frac{n}{2}}^n\binom{n}{k}$$
The wanted probability is - due to stochastic independence:
$$\sum_{k>\frac{n}{2}}^n\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$
since we chose $k$ $1$'s with probability $p$ and $n-k$ $0$'s with probability $1-p$

As for the possibility that one of the members votes positively and all the others wrong (I hope you meant this), we take into consideration all the strings that contain exactly one $1$, so, the wanted probability is:
$$\binom{n}{1}p(1-p)^{n-1}=np(1-p)^{n-1}$$

which is - evidently - smaller than the first one, since $p>0.5$.

If you meant that at least one votes positively, then we have all the strings with at lest one $1$, and the wanted probability is:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$
which is larger than the first one.

Comment: I think the OP wants to prove that $p<\sum_{k>n/2}\binom{n}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}$. The right is the probability that a committee of $n$ gets it right, while the left, $p$, is the probability that a committee of one member gets it right.

Comment: Yes Thomas that is what I want to prove, thanks for the help Βασίλης Μάρκος but its not what i meant.